# cakePHP URL rewrite rule for static pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

I'm using cakePHP. How do I write a rewrite rule for the following condition.

```
http://www.example.com/pages/about_us
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/about
```

and similar to contact_us and other pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

app/Config/routes.php

Router::connect('/about', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'about_us'));

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 301 redirect like so:

```
Redirect 301 /about_us http://www.example.com/about
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, i tried this one but won't work. :(

Comment: Have you specified "RewriteEngine on" (not in quotes) before your 301 or rewrite rules?

Comment: yeah this is my .htaccess file                               RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch temp ^/blog/wp-admin$ http://www.example.com/blog/wp-admin/
RewriteRule blog$ /blog/ [L]
RewriteRule blog/wp-admin$ /blog/wp-admin/ [L]
RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]